# Failing to push to a dev branch in git

Tags: git, azure, intellij-idea, azure-devops

I just recently started working on Azure and working with repos. I have no issues when it comes to pushing to master branch, but the moment I try to push to dev branch which a colleague created, I get the following error when pushing:

`fatal: 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository`
`fatal: Could not read from repository`

I used these commands `git push and git push dev`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The syntax is [`git push <repository> [<refspec>…​]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). In your case it's most probably `git push origin dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your actual branch with : `git status`, the name will be after `On branch`. Copy this name.

Then you can do : `git push origin localBranchName:RemoteBranch`

ex: 
If `git status` return `On branch main` 
To push on dev branch you need to do: `git push origin main:dev`